# How to solve CORS issue in Dunzo developer API while calling from nuxt js using AXIOS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Getting CORS error while calling Dunzo developer API the API base url is https://apis-staging.dunzo.in

my code is

```
await axios
    .get("https://apis-staging.dunzo.in/api/v1/token", {
      headers: {
        "client-id": "<MY_CLIENT_ID>",
        "client-secret": "<MY_CLIENT_SECRET>",
        "Accept-Language": "en_US",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return res.status(200).json(response);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("err =====", err);
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: err,
      });
    });
```

Comment: As always, since it's a CORS issue the answer would be: on the backend. Go to your dashboard or so, and set the CORS settings there.

Answer (score 2):

**THANKS TO KISSU I EDIT THIS POST (THIS IS NOT A PROPER SOLUTION)**

You can do this to bypass the `CORS` which is not recommended. Go to `nuxt.config.js` file and create something like this:

```js
axios: {
  proxy: true
},

proxy: {
  ‍'/api': {
    target: 'http://back-url:<some-port>/',
    pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' }
  }
}
```

Now, you can send requests like this:

```js
this.$axios.get('/api/some-getter-request')
```